# How to write subclass of ArrayFieldVector<Complex> (apache commons)

Tags: java, arrays, generics

There are **ArrayFieldVector** class in ApacheCommons:

```
    public class ArrayFieldVector<T extends FieldElement<T>> implements FieldVector<T>, Serializable
```

Now I need to work with complex vectors.

```
    ArrayFieldVector<Complex> c = new ArrayFieldVector<>(100, new Complex(1,0));
```

The problem is that there aren't pow method in **ArrayFieldVector** class. So I decided to write my own class:

```
  public class ComplexVector extends ArrayFieldVector<Complex>{
    Complex[] data=super.getDataRef();

    public ComplexVector(Complex[] c){
       super(c);
    }

    public ComplexVector pow(double p){
       Complex[] out=new Complex[data.length];
       for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           out[i]=data[i].pow(p);
                                     }
       return new ComplexVector(out);
  }
}
```

Now I can pow **ComplexVector** but can not add **ComplexVector** to **ArrayFieldVector** because there are no add method with **ComplexVector** argument. One of the solution is to rewrite all this metods (add, multiply, ebeAdd,...) with **ComplexVector** argument. Maybe there are other way to solve this problem?

Comment: `ComplexVector` is an `ArrayFieldVector`, do you need vector of vector?

Comment: @RC No, I want to calculate for example `(a+b)^3`, where `a` and `b` are `ComplexVector`. But I can not do it, because `a+b` is `ArrayFieldVector` and it doesn't see `pow` method from `ComlexVector` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use something like this:

```
public final class ArrayFieldVectorUtils {

    private ArrayFieldVectorUtils(){
        // avoid instantiation
    }

    public static ArrayFieldVector<Complex> pow(final ArrayFieldVector<Complex> a, int pow){
       Complex[] out = new Complex[a.length];
       for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           out[i]=a[i].pow(pow);
                                     }
       return new ArrayFieldVector<Complex>(out);
    }
}
```

Usage: `ArrayFieldVectorUtils.pow(someArrayFieldVector, 3)`

Comment: yes, it is a solution, but I would like to save notation and write `someComplexVector.pow(3)` because I should make a lot of calculations and writing `ArrayFieldVectorUtils.pow(someArrayFieldVector, 3)` will take a lot of time

Comment: Another solution would be to recreate a `ComplexVector` from the  `ArrayFieldVector` you get back from `add`.